# Gstreamer appsrc

Tags: c, gstreamer

Gstreamer (**version 0.10**) allow to load external data with "Appsrc" element.

Appsrc  has a control property that define how much data can be queued in appsrc before considers the queue full. It is named "max-bytes".

When queue size reached predefined limit appsrc signal with "enough-data" signal.

There is an application:

1. it has a feeding function X reading data from filesystem.
2. "start" and "stop" functions responsible for function X execution. Both functions registered with appsrc:

   ```
   g_signal_connect(app->appsrc_v, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(start_feed),   app);       
   g_signal_connect(app->appsrc_v, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK(stop_feed),    app);
   ```
3. queue limit defined with "max-bytes" property to : 40960 bytes

Everything seems defined well  - pipline is running, appsrc consuming data, feeding is working, appsrc emitting "need"& "enough" signals.

But sometimes  i can see the following:

```
appsrc gstappsrc.c:1451:gst_app_src_push_buffer_full:<appsrc_v> queue filled (**890033** >= **40960**)
appsrc gstappsrc.c:1451:gst_app_src_push_buffer_full:<appsrc_v> queue filled (**898225** >= **40960**)
appsrc gstappsrc.c:1451:gst_app_src_push_buffer_full:<appsrc_v> queue filled (**898225** >= **40960**)
```

Queue limit was reached but there is "enough" signal wasn't emitted.
Feeding function will continue to pushing data into appsrc and instead of 40K it can push upto 1Mb or more.

Can you help me to understand the cause of this?

Comment: How have you set the "max-byte" propertry, check the syntax of it. And also include the implementation of start-feed and stop-feed.